# SCSS nth-child select all childs

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I am trying to set a background different for each item-icon but it selects every elements instead of the first:

CSS part

```css
.dropdown-item-icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  &:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

HTML part with items and items icons:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="">
    <div class="dropdown-item">
      <div class="dropdown-item-icon"></div>
      <div class="dropdown-item-info">
        <span class="name">Browse</span>
        <p class="description">Challenges created by the community</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="">
    <div class="dropdown-item">
      <div class="dropdown-item-icon"></div>
      <div class="dropdown-item-info">
        <span class="name">My List</span>
        <p class="description">Joined and created challenges</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the pseudo selection `nth-child` only tries to match the immediate nth child of a parent element. Here, you are trying to get the first child of `.dropdown-item-icon` which gets you the immediate first child of its parent which is `dropdown-item`.

It works only when both of the `.dropdown-item-icon` are children of the same parent which is not the case here. However, `.dropdown-item-icon` is a child of `.dropdown-item` which is a child of the `a` tag. Both of the `a` tags are children of the container `.dropdown`. Hence to get the first `.dropdown-item-icon`, get the first `a` tag.

```css
a:first-child .dropdown-item .dropdown-item-icon {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

Take a look at the following code snippet:

```css
.dropdown-item-icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

a:first-child .dropdown-item .dropdown-item-icon {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <!-- parent child -->
  <a href="">
    <div class="dropdown-item">
      <div class="dropdown-item-icon"></div>

      <div class="dropdown-item-info">
        <span class="name">Browse</span>
        <p class="description">Challenges created by the community</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <!-- parent-child -->
  <a href="">
    <div class="dropdown-item">
      <div class="dropdown-item-icon">

      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-item-info">
        <span class="name">My List</span>
        <p class="description">Joined and created challenges</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```